# How do I keep a Visual Studio library project from "pushing" out its DLLs to web projects when being built?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This is a hard concept to get across in the title, so forgive me if it doesn't fully capture the idea.

Perhaps I am crazy, but I just noticed this behavior:

1. Create Visual Studio solution
2. Create DLL library project (I use C# ... don't know if the behavior is the same with another language-specific DLL project).
3. Create web client A (I used an MVC 3 project)
4. Reference the library from the new web client A
5. Create web client B (I used an ASP.NET project)
6. Reference the library from the new web client B
7. Build the solution
8. Wait a bit (at least a minute so that the timestamp difference will be obvious)
9. Open two Windows Explorer windows: one to the bin in web client A and one to the bin in web client B.  You should see the binaries for the client project as well as the library project (assuming that "Copy local" for project references is a universal default)
10. Build *just the library project*.

On my system, the library DLL appears to be *pushed* (or mutually *pulled*) into the client bin folders.  This should be evident by the timestamp difference if you wait at step 8.  Again, perhaps I'm crazy but I know I've done this scenario before and never seen this behavior.

The problem came up because I was working in a solution with this type of arrangement and was building two web applications individually as opposed to building the whole solution.  When I would build web app A, it worked fine, but web app B would complain with a "FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly" error.  And then vice-versa.

So to the question:

Is this normal behavior (and either I'm crazy or am wrong about being in this scenario before)?

If not normal, is there a setting I can use to make the library DLL only get into the client when the client gets built?

Comment: This is weird. If you build the dll it should only be build on the solution bin folder. How do it know where to push it?? Maybe there is something more on your build?? are you sure nobody add post build operation to copy it?

Comment: @gbianchi - If you follow the steps above with no existing solution loaded, this behavior still happens. i.e. definitely no post build actions, etc.  Only default behavior ... "default" on my machine at least.

Comment: Shot in the dark: could this be ReSharper doing this for some intellisense need it has?

Comment: But you have one solution loaded, the dll ;) just for the fun of it, what if you build it at command line, still same behavior?

Comment: Using MSBUILD against the library project on the command line, no the DLLs are not showing up in the client bin folders.

Comment: no post build actions? I don't know about resharper, but doesn't look like a good behavior from it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the copy local setting on the references to the class library.

**edit**

Just checked and the same happens on my machine.
I think that this is default behaviour. If you think about it, it allows you to rebuild a class library and use it in the referencing project without building that project.

Comment: I mention that in step 9 above.  I thought that this was a setting that allowed "bin deployment" as opposed to having to have a DLL in the GAC.  Admittedly, I see that turning "Copy local" off still has the library DLL being copied into the client bin.

Comment: I verified that the "Copy Local" setting is irrelevant here.  Even if I turn it off for the client project, the new library DLL still shows up in the client bin folder when the library is built.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's somewhat comforting to see it's not just me.  And now I realize why I'm having the initial assembly loading/binding problem ... the library in the "real" solution I was working on is a strongly-named library, so it was choking due to the version being auto-incremented.

Comment: The above "copy local" issue remains, though.  In a "clean" setup as I outlined in my steps above, the copy local setting has no effect; the library DLL is still copied to the client projects.  Any idea why?  Do you have the same behavior?

Comment: Yes if I clean a class library project and rebuild it, the output DLL is copied into the bin directory of any project that references it, irrespective of whether "copy local" is set or not.